# How to run .jar file using a specific JRE version from a .bat file?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

So I'm trying to run a jar file which requires Java 7. I installed java 7 JRE but when i use `java -jar...` its still using java 8.

This is what I have in the `.bat` file I'm trying to run and `mcpc-plus-1.4.7.jar` is in the same folder as the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar mcpc-plus-1.4.7.jar -Xms1G -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M nogui -nojline
```

One thing to note when I open the Command Prompt and run `java -jar ...` it works as it should, but it downloads and creates everything in the JRE location, which is not what I want.

This is what I get after running the suggested commands within the comments.

```
Environment variable JAVA_HOME,  not defined

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
D:\Programs\brackets\command;
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
D:\Programs\Nmap)
```

Comment: And isn't your solution working?

Comment: When jar is run it it is spouse to download required libraries and create files needed to run in the same folder but all it does from that is like 20%(only libraries downloaded and one empty folder) and in command prompt i also get different results as well as not being able to type anything there.

Comment: What is the output from running these three lines from a batch file? `@Set JAVA_HOME`, `@Echo(%PATH%`, and `@Pause`? Please post that output, correctly formatted into your question, by way of [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60712108/edit).

Comment: @Compo i have eddied the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common practice to set HAVA_HOME to point to the JDK or JRE you want to use, then execute %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe with the necessary parameters.

This allows you to choose the Java version by setting one simple variable.